# Powershell script deleting files despite -Exclude switch

Tags: powershell

I have the following script where I'm trying to delete all the SQL .bak files except for the last two. When I run it it wipes out everything in the folder. Does -Exclude not work with array values?

```
$excludefile=get-childitem D:\TempDB | sort lastwritetime | select-object -Last 2 | select-object -Property Name | select-object -expandproperty Name    

foreach ($element in $excludefile)
{
    $element
    remove-item -Path D:\TempDB -Exclude ($element) -Force 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Get-ChildItem D:\TempDB |
  Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
  Select-Object -Skip 2 |
  Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

Of course, you can remove `-WhatIf` if this is what you need.